# AngularDart: is there a hook that is called when component is rendered?

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I am trying to access `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight` property on a `<div>` element to decide whether to show 'View more' link or not:

```
<div #clippedContainer class="clipped">
  <some-other-component></some-other-component>
  <a class="view-more" href="...">View more</a>
</div>
```

```
.clipped {
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.view-more {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 550px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;

  .displayed {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```
@ViewChild('clippedContainer', read: Element)
set clippedContainer(Element container) {
  if (container.scrollHeight > container.clientHeight) {
    container.querySelector('.learn-more').classes.add('displayed');
  }
}
```

The issue is that scrollHeight is 0 at the moment of the call because component is not yet displayed. I've tried reading it inside `scheduleMicrotask` and `ngAfterViewInit`, but it's still 0. I've found a hack, which waits a second to let browser compute the layout and then accesses needed properties:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then(() {
  if (container.scrollHeight > container.clientHeight) {
    container.querySelector('.learn-more').classes.add('displayed');
  }
});
```

but this introduces an unwanted delay between content being rendered and link appearing. Is there a better way to detect when layout has been computed and `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight` are available?

**Update:** I have discovered that part of the issue is that the component that contains the `<div>` is constructed dynamically by a popup framework. It appears hooks such as `ngAfterViewInit` are executed even before the component is attached to the DOM.

Comment: I think that in ngAfterViewInit you has already the elements rendered

Comment: As mentioned in my question I have tried using `ngAfterViewInit` and it doesn't work. After digging a bit deeper, I have discovered that this component is instantiated by the popup framework that we use. My current theory is that hooks are run before it is attached to the DOM. In fact, the framework internally uses `NgZone.onTurnStart` to repeatedly check when `Element.parent` field gets set to determine when it is added to the DOM. I've read a bit on `NgZone` and plan to investigate if I can use a similar approach or even add a hook to have the popup framework invoke it for me.

Comment: Can you update the question to reflect that this is a custom popup problem or add to the answer?

Comment: Posted an update. I have also posted a solution based on the code that I found inside the popup framework, but hopefully someone can find a better one.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one way to detect when the component is attached to the DOM, but I don't really like this approach as it's quite complicated. Hopefully someone can come up with a better solution.

```
class MyComponent {
  final NgZone _ngZone;
  final Element _hostElement;

  MyComponent(this._ngZone, this._hostElement);

  @ViewChild('clippedContainer', read: Element)
  Element container;

  void ngAfterViewInit() {
    final sub = _ngZone.onTurnStart.listen((_) {
      if (_hostElement.parent == null) return;
      sub.cancel();

      if (container.scrollHeight > container.clientHeight) {
        container.querySelector('.learn-more').classes.add('displayed');
      }
    });
  }
}
```